# JAVA Web Service with SOAP Client Objective C---Response problem

Tags: java, objective-c, http, soap, http-status-code-404

I have this web service in Java:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "Catalogo_V1")
public class Catalogo_V1 {

    /** This is a sample web service operation */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) 
    {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }
}
```

and this part in Objective C (after generate code with WSDL2ObjC):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender 
{

    Catalogo_V1PortBinding *binding = [[Catalogo_V1Svc Catalogo_V1PortBinding] initWithAddress:@"http://localhost:8080/WSServer/Catalogo_V1.wsdl"];
    binding.logXMLInOut = YES;  // to get logging to the console.

    Catalogo_V1Svc_hello *r = [[Catalogo_V1Svc_hello alloc] init];

    //NSLog(@"request: %@",r);

    [r setName:i.text];
    //NSLog(@"string: %@ ",i.text);

    Catalogo_V1PortBindingResponse *resp = [binding helloUsingParameters:(Catalogo_V1Svc_hello *)r];

    NSLog(@"response: %@",resp);

    for (id mine in resp.bodyParts)
    {
        if ([mine isKindOfClass:[Catalogo_V1Svc_helloResponse class]])
        {
            //lab.text = [mine Catalogo_V1Svc_helloResponse];
        }
    }
}
```

and my console show this messages:

2

```
011-08-30 17:00:11.572 Catalogo-V1[3876:207] OutputHeaders:
{
    "Content-Length" = 451;
    "Content-Type" = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
    Host = localhost;
    Soapaction = "";
    "User-Agent" = wsdl2objc;
}
2011-08-30 17:00:11.572 Catalogo-V1[3876:207] OutputBody:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:Catalogo_V1Svc="http://org/" xsl:version="1.0">
  <soap:Body>
    <Catalogo_V1Svc:hello>
      <Catalogo_V1Svc:name>ddddddd</Catalogo_V1Svc:name>
    </Catalogo_V1Svc:hello>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
2011-08-30 17:00:11.593 Catalogo-V1[3876:207] Response HTTP:
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x5b1ffd0>
2011-08-30 17:00:11.593 Catalogo-V1[3876:207] ResponseStatus: 404
2011-08-30 17:00:11.593 Catalogo-V1[3876:207] ResponseHeaders:
{
    "Content-Length" = 1067;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Tue, 30 Aug 2011 15:00:11 GMT";
    Server = "GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1";
    "X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 Java/Apple Inc./1.6)";
}
2011-08-30 17:00:11.617 Catalogo-V1[3876:207] ResponseError:
Error Domain=Catalogo_V1PortBindingResponseHTTP Code=404 "not found" UserInfo=0x5b2a320 {NSLocalizedDescription=not found}
2011-08-30 17:00:11.618 Catalogo-V1[3876:207] response: <Catalogo_V1PortBindingResponse: 0x5b25bd0>
```

the output its correct but i dont recieve any response....

Comment: Error 404 means that your client isn't responding correctly.

Comment: Ok, the problem is in the client, but where????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server responds with [HTTP status 404 (File Not Found)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404), which means that the client is posting its SOAP request to an endpoint (URL) that the server isn't configured to respond to.

For example, your client might be directed at `http://localhost:8080/foo`
but the server is listening at `http://localhost/bar`.

Check the endpoint URL on your client and the server configuration to ensure it is listening at the same URL.

Comment: Thanks Maerics!!! -->> this is the correct form "http://localhost:8080/WSServer/Catalogo_V1" but i have other little problem in the last "if", i dont know how extract my param...

Comment: There are LOTS of things that can cause an error 404: invalid/missing port#, bad/incomplete URL, invalid namespace, unexpected/invalid character, etc etc.  The only common root cause is "the client messed up" :)

Comment: Now i dont have any error but my server return response without my parameter sended..... A lot of thanks!! when dont know about something is so difficult solve any problem...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255688/objective-c-soap-client-request-problem