# Objective-C SOAP Client --Request Problem?

Tags: objective-c, httprequest, soap-client

I have generated code with WSDL2OBJC.
I have big problem with request in my Objective C client:

```
CatalogoPortBinding *binding = [[CatalogoSvc CatalogoPortBinding] initWithAddress:@"http://localhost:8080/WSServer/Catalogo_V1"];
    binding.logXMLInOut = YES;  // to get logging to the console.

    CatalogoSvc_hello *request = [[CatalogoSvc_hello alloc] init];

    NSString *t = @"David";
    request.name = t;

    NSLog(@"request: %@",request.name);

    CatalogoPortBindingResponse *response = [binding helloUsingParameters:request];


    //NSLog(@"%@",resp.bodyParts);
    for (id mine in response.bodyParts)
    {

        NSLog(@"name: %@",[mine return_]);
        if ([mine isKindOfClass:[CatalogoSvc_helloResponse class]])
        {   
            if (sec == YES) {

                //NSLog(@"name: %@",[mine return_]);
                NSString *texto = (NSString*)[mine return_];
                [lab setText:(NSString*)texto];
            }
        }

    }
```

my console show:

```
2011-08-31 12:29:05.086 Catalogo-V1[3596:207] request: David
2011-08-31 12:29:05.088 Catalogo-V1[3596:207] OutputHeaders:
{
    "Content-Length" = 434;
    "Content-Type" = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
    Host = localhost;
    Soapaction = "";
    "User-Agent" = wsdl2objc;
}
2011-08-31 12:29:05.088 Catalogo-V1[3596:207] OutputBody:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:CatalogoSvc="http://org/" xsl:version="1.0">
  <soap:Body>
    <CatalogoSvc:hello>
      <CatalogoSvc:name>David</CatalogoSvc:name>
    </CatalogoSvc:hello>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
2011-08-31 12:29:05.093 Catalogo-V1[3596:207] ResponseStatus: 200
2011-08-31 12:29:05.094 Catalogo-V1[3596:207] ResponseHeaders:
{
    "Content-Type" = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 31 Aug 2011 10:29:05 GMT";
    Server = "GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 Java/Apple Inc./1.6)";
}
2011-08-31 12:29:05.094 Catalogo-V1[3596:207] ResponseBody:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:helloResponse xmlns:ns2="http://org/"><return>Hello null !</return></ns2:helloResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope>
2011-08-31 12:29:05.095 Catalogo-V1[3596:207] name: Hello null !
```

I need to show this message: "Hello David !" and i receive: "Hello null!".

Comment: I NEED HELP .......i have generated a lot of different web services in Java and the result is the same, i know that the problem is in the objective c SOAP client. I have showed this tutorial and i have followed this --> http://myblack.net/showthread.php?399-iPhone-Development-Accessing-SOAP-Services-with-WSDL2ObjC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comparing this request to what you have in [your question posted about a manual solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7280851/830760), it looks like you've got namespace issues happening here. The SOAP request generated here applies the http://org/ namespace (via the identifier CatalogoSvc) to the "name" element:

```
<CatalogoSvc:hello>
  <CatalogoSvc:name>David</CatalogoSvc:name>
</CatalogoSvc:hello>
```

In the manual scenario where you have gotten this to work, the http://org/ namespace is applied to the surrounding "hello" element but not the "name" element:

```
<ns2:hello xmlns:ns2="http://org/>
    <name>david</name>
</ns2:hello>
```

Based on this observation, I would deduce that your service is not expecting a namespace to be applied to the name element, so it is not finding that parameter when it is sent with a namespace.

To fix this problem you will need to either:

1. Figure out how to tell the SOAP client stub generation to NOT apply a namespace to your parameter, or
2. Update your service to make it expect a namespaced "name" element.

Since the client side code is presumably generated from the service's WSDL, I suspect that the Objective-C code is doing it right and your service code has it wrong, but that's just a suspicion. Either way, you need to find a way to make client and server side "agree"

Comment: Good observation Tim but wsdl2objc generate more difficult request:       <?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:CatalogoSvc="http://org/" xsl:version="1.0">
  <soap:Body>
    <CatalogoSvc:hello>
      <CatalogoSvc:name>David</CatalogoSvc:name>
    </CatalogoSvc:hello>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>  and in this part:  xmlns:CatalogoSvc="http://org/"  say the same that manually.

Comment: However if you have time, u can test my situation. I only have done a default web service in web java application with Netbeans. After have tested this web service and generated wsdl2objc code. Finally with simple objective c app i have done a SOAP client using wsdl2objc code (the same client that at first in this question). Is so simple exercise but ....

Comment: It still looks like the same problem. Both the SudzC and the wsdl2objc libraries apply a namespace to the "name" element. The manual example that you say is working does not. Your service is most likely failing because it is not recognizing the input parameters when a namespace has been applied.

Comment: XML namespaces have nothing to do with Java packages and how they form a natural namespace. Your server-side is expecting XML that looks a certain way, and your auto-generated clients don't know that. They are instead creating XML that looks the way that the service WSDL says it should. You should look at how you've implemented your service and how the WebService/WebParam annotations work to see if they can more accurately match up with the WSDL.

Comment: ok, i understand, the probably problem is my namespace... In java is normal save your classes in some package. And in my web service i have "org" group. Its true that in wsdl url dont specify this. I dont know how include this information.

Comment: I havent implemented nothing in my web service, i only have created and used default method "hello". I think that in the wsdl file show web service namespace, similar to this lines: <portType name="Catalogo">
<operation name="hello">
<input wsam:Action="http://org/Catalogo/helloRequest" message="tns:hello" />
<output wsam:Action="http://org/Catalogo/helloResponse" message="tns:helloResponse" />
</operation>
</portType>

Comment: The WSDL will directly or indirectly describe the type of the helloRequest message using an XML schema. That is where any expected namespace is declared. If you were to use a wsdl2java tool to create server side skeletons, that would likely take care of things. Otherwise you need to look at other options (do it manually in Objective-c, change your WSDL to match what your service is doing, or fix the server)

Comment: I think that i,ve found the solution modifying wsdl2objc code, in xmlNodeForDoc method, changing "xmlNodePtr node = xmlNewDocNode(doc, NULL, (const xmlChar*)[elName UTF8String], NULL);" for this: "xmlNodePtr node = xmlNewDocNode(doc, myNS, (const xmlChar*)[elName UTF8String], NULL);" where myNS is: "xmlNsPtr myNS = xmlSearchNs(doc, root, (const xmlChar*)"myNameSpace");" I will try with this..

Comment: THANK FOR ALL TIM!!! I,ve solved my problem, was in this line:  <ns2:hello xmlns:ns2="http://org/>

Answer (score 2):

i had same problem until suggestion at below...

According to what you've shown from your console, the XML request you formulated is invalid. You have

```
<ns2:hello xmlns:ns2="http://org/" />
    <name>david</name>
</ns2:hello>
```

But you should have (note the removal of the invalid XML tag termination):

```
<ns2:hello xmlns:ns2="http://org/>
    <name>david</name>
</ns2:hello>
```

Also note that your working sample request includes a soap:Header element, and yours does not. That is unlikely to be the problem here though.